# Removing a character from 'iskeyword' in vim

Tags: vim

In my vimrc, I have included a script (say, otherscript.vim, which I need to include for work reasons) that says:

```
autocmd FileType php setlocal iskeyword+=$
```

and I don't want this behaviour. So, sometime later in the vimrc, I say:

```
autocmd FileType php setlocal iskeyword-=$
```

(I also tried using `set` instead of `setlocal`.) But, when I open a php file, iskeyword still contains the $ symbol in it. I am using vim 7.2. The output of ':verbose set iskeyword' is

```
iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,$
    Last set from /path/to/otherscript.vim
```

The output of ':scriptnames' is:

```
...
7: /usr/share/vim/vim72/ftplugin.vim
8: /home/yogeshwer/.vimrc
...
74: /path/to/otherscript.vim
...
```

Can somebody help me how I can revert the changes to 'iskeyword' made by the other script? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Do you have other `FileType php` autocommands?

Comment: @Neil: I am not sure where will that be, but the output of ':set ft' is 'filetype=php', so it must be set somewhere. Let me know how I can provide the information you were asking.

Comment: Make a copy of that script and edit it?

Comment: Well, I simplified the question. The real story is that there are like 50 such scripts that are loaded, and there are dependencies in them. So, copying is probably not what I want to do... they also keep getting updated in Git, so if I make a copy, then it will be hard to keep them updated. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: What's the output of `:au FileType php`?

Answer (score 6):

I like to avoid autocmds when I can and use the `after` directory structure.

```sh
$ mkdir -p ~/.vim/after/{ftplugin,syntax,indent}
$ echo 'setlocal iskeyword-=$' >> ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim
```

This sets up a basic `after` directory in your user-specific vim config folder.  Whereas `~/.vim/ftplugin/$FILETYPE.vim` would be used in lieu of vim's standard $FILETYPE.vim file, files in an `after` directory get executed after, allowing you to override or change the behavior of your ftplugins, syntax definitions, and indent commands.

As an additional example to show you how these work, I'll include part of my local `after/syntax/python.vim` file here. I like all the "structural punctuation" of my code to stand out when I read it, so I do this:

```
syn match pythonParen /[()]/
syn match pythonBrack /[][]/
syn match pythonCurly /[{}]/
hi def link pythonParen Paren
hi def link pythonBrack Brack
hi def link pythonCurly Curly
```

I've also got an `after/indent/php.vim` file that was supposed to fix some of the annoying indent issues I ran into with the indent behavior when switching in and out of `<?php ?>` regions in a template file, but the code is a mess and never really worked in the first place, so I won't reproduce it here. I mention it only to give you an example of what can be done with the after hooks.