# the dollar sign `$` cannot be removed from iskeyword

Tags: vim

in my .vimrc, I tried both

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.php set iskeyword-=$
```

and

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.php set iskeyword-=\$
```

but still it's not working, the $ is still in `iskeyword` when opening a php file

Comment: Are you sure there's not something else adding it to `iskeyword` after this because it's not in `iskeyword` for me when I open a file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14718009/390913